# Doctrine 2 ArrayCollection::add() persists items in reverse order

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm making multiple calls to `$this->myDependentEntityCollection[] = $myDependentEntity;` (being it a type of `ArrayCollection` or `PersistentCollection` before calling `persist()` and `flush()` on the independent  entity (using `cascade=persist`).

However, the dependent entities in the collection are being persisted in the reverse order than the one they're added (I'm guessing they use a stack, then pop items one by one).

Take the following example for a `Order` and `Item` with a `1:N` relationship:

```
// Order.php
/* (...doctrine stuff...,  cascade={"persist"}) */
protected $items;

public function addItem(Item $item) {
    $item->setOrder($this);
    $this->items[] = $item;
}

// Item.php
public function setOrder(Order $order) {
   $this->order = $order;
}

// Somewhere else in the code
$order->addItem($item1);
$order->addItem($item2);
$order->addItem($item3);

$em->persist($order);
$em->flush();
```

They get persisted in the order `item3`, `item2`, `item1`;  rather than `1,2,3`.

How can I make it so that they get saved in the correct order?

Comment: you could try to sort them before persisting....

Comment: @Matteo I'd like that approach. Not sure how to sort with ArrayCollection though.

Comment: Kinda off-topic but does it matter? I always thought we shouldn't rely on the order of records in database. The order of these items should be set when you retrieve them instead IMO. Interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: @Veve you're correct. The reason behind this is kind of a bad practice we already have and it's probably not going to change anytime soon,  where devs checks registries directly in the DB and decide something is working or not by the order it was added with the primary key (since the timestamps are all screwed and may need a major refactor).

Answer (score 3):

Try using [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

> array_unshift — Prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an
>   array

as example:

```
public function addItem(Item $item) {
    $item->setOrder($this);
    array_unshift($this->items, $item);
}
```

Hope this help

NOTE:

As in the comment Christopher Francisco say, is not possibile to pass a ArrayCollection object to the array_unshift function, so a trick can be the following:

```
public function addItem(Item $item) {
    $item->setOrder($this);
    $itemsAsArray = $this->items->toArray();
    array_unshift($itemsAsArray, $item);
    $this->items = new ArrayCollection($itemsAsArray);
}
```

Otherwise, you could implement a method on the object that [inverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) the order of the array and call it before persisting, but is more error prone (You could forgot to call the method).

Comment: Note `$this->items` is actually an `ArrayCollection`, not an `array`, will this still work?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherFrancisco you are right! I update my answer with a workaround